# Yii2 валидация dynamic input на клиенте

Tags: yii2, form, валидация

Есть поле формы вида

```
$form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['accept' => 'image/*'])->label(false)
```

Поля добавляются динамически на клиенте, через jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '#add_image', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $('.block').length;

        console.log(id);

        var image_block = '<input type="hidden" name="Item[imageFiles]['+id+']" value=""><input type="file" id="item-imagefiles-'+id+'" name="Item[imageFiles]['+id+']" accept="image/*">';

        $('.images').append(image_block);
    });
```

Но Yii2 в упор их не видит, как будто их вообще нет, т.е. остальные поля проходят валидацию, а этих как совсем и не уществует :(

Нашел https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/forms-activeform-js.md

Пишу

`$('#w0').yiiActiveForm('add', {
            'id': 'item-imagefiles-'+id+'',
            'name': 'imageFiles['+id+']',
            'container': '.field-item-imagefiles-'+id+'',
            'input': '#item-imagefiles-'+id+'',
            'error': '.help-block'
        });`

Вообще ничего не происходит, хотя насколько я понял, это должно добавлять валидацию поля на клиенте ?

P.S: понятно что можно это отправить на сервер, вернуть ответ и т.д. Но интересует именно валидация на клиенте.

На клиенте не получается, отправляю на сервер, получаю ответ в формате json, 2 проблемы

1. Как 'прилепить' сообщение к нужному элементу формы ?
2. Если поле изображения не заполнено, оно его игнорит, т.к. сам Yii если пустое поле, его не учитывает, т.е. получаю изображения таким образом:

   $model->images = UploadedFile::getInstancesByName('Item[images]');

Если с 5 файловых инпутов 3 оставить пустыми, то валидация пройдет только для 2, остальные 3 вообще не попадут на валидацию, хотя в модели правила задано правило

```
[['images'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос,то прилепить "сообщение" можно так:

```
   $('#w0').yiiActiveForm('updateMessages', {
        'item-imagefiles-'+id+'': ['sometext'],
    }, true);
```

Лучше конечно назначить id для формы явно,использование #w0 может привести к баге,ну у меня был такой претендент,я предупредил.

Также получается что еще нужно закодить массив к примеру где хранятся все назначенные айди новых динамических инпутов,что бы можно было удобно брать их оттуда и еще навесить на них нужные вам обработчики нужных событий.
Вот еще обратите внимание на вот этот кусок кода 
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L498
То есть повидимому можно использовать что то подобное:

```
$('#w0').yiiActiveForm('validateAttribute',$form, attribute, forceValidate, validationDelay);
```